# Displacement of drawer instead overlay react navigation createDrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-drawer

I'm using react-navigation(2.14.2) in my react native project and I want to use a drawer which has displacement effect instead of overlay. To be clear -

I want this
[image]

What react-navigation gives is this -

[image]

How can I achieve displacement in createDrawerNavigator?